# Can a java method implementing a base class method return an inherited class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say I have the standard Draw class with inherited classes of Circle and Square. Is there a way to do the following? Maybe with generics?

```
class Draw {
  public abstract Draw duplicate();
}

class Circle extends Draw {
  public Circle duplicate() {
    return new Circle();
  }
}

class Square extends Draw {
  public Square duplicate() {
    return new Square();
  }
}
```

Comment: Draw should be an abstract class.  Otherwise it looks fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have an overriding method return a type that is a subclass of the superclass method's return type.  This technique, called "covariant return types", is described [at the bottom of a Java tutorial on return types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).  This works because a `Circle` and a `Square` are `Draw`s, so even if you have a superclass reference, and you don't know or care which subclass you really have, you still are guaranteed to get back a `Draw`.

Incidentally, to get your code to compile, you just need to make the `Draw` class `abstract`.  Everything else, including the covariant return types, looks fine.

Comment: Oh wow, that is super easy. This is the downside of being in Java forever, you don't know when these new things happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can since Java 5.

Since Java 5, a method in a subclass may return an object whose type is a subclass of the type returned by the method with the same signature in the superclass. ([source](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/covariant-return-types.html)). This is called covariant return types.

Answer (score 1):

I would use generics here:

```
class Draw<T> {
  public abstract T duplicate();
}

class Circle extends Draw<Circle> {
  @Override
  public Circle duplicate() {
    return new Circle();
  }
}

class Square extends Draw<Square> {
  @Override
  public Square duplicate() {
    return new Square();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex, can you expand on why you would use generics? It seems redundant.

Comment: You can not do type safe utility methods based on the superclass without generics...

Comment: Something like `public static <T extends Draw<T>> T duplicate(T draw) { return draw.duplicate(); }`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is the following:

```
public abstract class Draw<T extends Draw> {
    public abstract T duplicate();
}

public class Circle extends Draw<Circle> {
    @Override
    public Circle duplicate() {
        return new Circle();
    }
}

public class Square extends Draw<Square> {
    @Override
    public Square duplicate() {
        return new Square();
    }
}
```

1. Use of the generics (with constraint on `T`, that should extend `Draw`, to avoid weird inheritance such as `Circle extends Draw<List>`)
2. Add `abstract` keyword to the `Draw` class

Then, you can do the following:

```
Square originalSquare = new Square();
Circle originalCircle = new Circle();

Square duplicatedSquare = originalSquare.duplicate();
Circle duplicatedCircle = originalCircle.duplicate();
```

---

**EDIT**

Without the generics, you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class Draw {
    public abstract Draw duplicate();
}

public class Circle extends Draw {
    @Override
    public Circle duplicate() {
        return new Circle();
    }
}

public class Square extends Draw {
    @Override
    public Square duplicate() {
        return new Square();
    }
}
```

Thanks to Pavel, rgettman and Enno Shioji , I did not know about "covariant return type".

Comment: Have you actually read the other answers? You can do what you are describing without the use of generics.

Comment: I hadn't seen the other answer before writing my own answer. I did not know about covariant return types, thank you.